# How to change video format to MP4 using Python

Tags: jquery, python, html

I did a project using Python. In that, I recorded and saved a video using client-side camera (HTML and jQuery) and I retrieved the value in Python using the `request.stream` method. However, I got the output in some format which I don't know what it is.

I want the saved video in mp4 format. How do I convert it to mp4 format using python? Can anyone help me?

Here is my code:

**html:**

```
<script src="https://webrtcexperiment-webrtc.netdna-ssl.com/RecordRTC.js"></script>
    <section class="experiment">
        <div class="inner">
            <button style="float: right;" id="fit-to-screen">Fit to Screen!</button>
            <label for="canvas-width-input">Canvas Width</label>
            <input type="text" id="canvas-width-input" value="320">
            <br />
            <label for="canvas-height-input">Canvas Height</label>
            <input type="text" id="canvas-height-input" value="240">
            <br />
            <div>
                <button id="record-video">Record</button>
                <button id="pause-resume-video" disabled>Pause</button>
                <button id="stop-recording-video" disabled>Stop</button>
                <hr>
                <h2 id="video-url-preview"></h2>
                <br>
                <input type="checkbox" id="record-screen" style="width:auto;">
                <label for="record-screen">Record Screen</label>
                <br>


                <video id="video" type="video/mp4" autoplay loop controls muted></video>

            </div>
        </div>

    </section>
    <form action="/video_upload" method="post"   enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <input type="hidden" id="two" name="two">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>

    <script>
        (function() {
            var params = {},
                r = /([^&=]+)=?([^&]*)/g;

            function d(s) {
                return decodeURIComponent(s.replace(/\+/g, ' '));
            }

            var match, search = window.location.search;
            while (match = r.exec(search.substring(1)))
                params[d(match[1])] = d(match[2]);

            window.params = params;
        })();
    </script>

    <script>
    function getByID(id) {
        return document.getElementById(id);
    }

    var recordVideo = getByID('record-video'),
        pauseResumeVideo = getByID('pause-resume-video'),
        stopRecordingVideo = getByID('stop-recording-video');

    var canvasWidth_input = getByID('canvas-width-input'),
        canvasHeight_input = getByID('canvas-height-input');

    if(params.canvas_width) {
        canvasWidth_input.value = params.canvas_width;
    }

    if(params.canvas_height) {
        canvasHeight_input.value = params.canvas_height;
    }

    var video = getByID('video');

    var videoConstraints = {
        audio: false,
        video: {
            mandatory: {},
            optional: []
        }
    };

    </script>

    <script>
    var screen_constraints;
    function isCaptureScreen(callback) {
        if (document.getElementById('record-screen').checked) {
            document.getElementById('fit-to-screen').onclick();

            getScreenId(function (error, sourceId, _screen_constraints) {
                if(error === 'not-installed') {
                    window.open('');
                }

                if(error === 'permission-denied') {
                    alert('Screen capturing permission is denied.');
                }

                if(error === 'installed-disabled') {
                    alert('Please enable chrome screen capturing extension.');
                }

                if(_screen_constraints) {
                    screen_constraints = _screen_constraints.video;
                    videoConstraints = _screen_constraints;
                }
                else {
                    videoConstraints = screen_constraints;
                }

                callback();
            });
        }
        else {
            callback();
        }
    }

    recordVideo.onclick = function() {
        isCaptureScreen(function() {
            recordVideoOrGIF(true);
        });
    };


    function recordVideoOrGIF(isRecordVideo) {
        navigator.getUserMedia(videoConstraints, function(stream) {
            video.onloadedmetadata = function() {
                video.width = canvasWidth_input.value || 320;
                video.height = canvasHeight_input.value || 240;

                var options = {
                    type: isRecordVideo ? 'video' : 'gif',
                    video: video,
                    canvas: {
                        width: canvasWidth_input.value,
                        height: canvasHeight_input.value
                    },
                    disableLogs: params.disableLogs || false,
                    recorderType: null // to let RecordRTC choose relevant types itself
                };

                recorder = window.RecordRTC(stream, options);
                recorder.startRecording();

                video.onloadedmetadata = false;
            };
            video.src = URL.createObjectURL(stream);
        }, function() {
            if (document.getElementById('record-screen').checked) {
                if (location.protocol === 'https:')
                    alert('<https> is mandatory to capture screen.');
                else
                    alert('Multi-capturing of screen is not allowed. Capturing process is denied. Are you enabled flag: "Enable screen capture support in getUserMedia"?');
            } else
                alert('Webcam access is denied.');
        });

        window.isAudio = false;

        if (isRecordVideo) {
            recordVideo.disabled = true;
            stopRecordingVideo.disabled = false;
            pauseResumeVideo.disabled = false;
        }
    }


    stopRecordingVideo.onclick = function() {
        this.disabled = true;
        recordVideo.disabled = false;

        if (recorder)
    recorder.stopRecording(function(url) {
            video.src = url;
            video.play();
            document.getElementById("two").value = video.src;
            document.getElementById('video-url-preview').innerHTML = '<a href="' + url + '" target="_blank" download="sp.mp4">Save</a>';
        });}

    </script>
<script>

</script>

    <script>
    document.getElementById('fit-to-screen').onclick = function() {
        this.disabled = true;

        video.width = canvasWidth_input.value = innerWidth;
        video.height = canvasHeight_input.value = innerHeight;
    };
    </script>
```

Here is Python code:

**py:**

```
from flask import Flask,render_template,request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return render_template("video.html")

@app.route('/video_upload', methods=['POST','GET'])
def main():
    if request.method == "POST":
     form = request.stream
     print form

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: Your task #1 is going to identify the format you are receiving the video (and audio) in. Have you tried to save it to a file and use a tools like vlc to open it?

Comment: yeah.. i have saved my downloaded video in  normal downloads path from that path i want to retrieve my saved video i have saved and tried but my format is look like "0x03C7B8F0" but  i don't know which format is it but i want this in MP4 format.

Comment: does the saved video format "0x03C7B8F0" play ?

Comment: No sir., i want to open this  video file in MP4 using my python